# SQLAlchemy used in Flask, Session management implementation

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

As I cannot use the Flask-SQLAlchemy due to models definitions and use of the database part of the app in other contexts than Flask, I found several ways to manage sessions and I am not sure what to do.

One thing that everyone seems to agree (including me) is that a new session should be created at the beginning of each request and be committed + closed when the request has been processed and the response is ready to be sent back to the client.

---

Currently, I implemented the session management that way:

I have a database initialization python script which creates the engine (`engine = create_engine(app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_URI"])`) and defines the session maker `Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False)`.
In another file I defined two function decorated with flask's `before_request` and `teardown_request` applications decorators.

```py
@app.before_request
def create_db_session():
    g.db_session = Session()

@app.teardown_request
def close_db_session(exception):
    try:
        g.db_session.commit()
    except:
        g.db_session.rollback()
    finally:
        g.db_session.close()
```

I then use the `g.db_session` when I need to perform queries: `g.db_session.query(models.User.user_id).filter_by(username=username)`

Is this a correct way to manage sessions ?

---

I also took a look at the [scoped sessions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html?highlight=scoped#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session) proposed by SQLAlchemy and this might be anotherway of doing things, but I am not sure about how to change my system to use scoped sessions...
If I understood it well, I would not use the `g` variable, but I would instead always refer to the `Session` definition declared by `Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False))` and I would not need to initialize a new session explicitly when a request arrives.
I could just perform my queries as usual with `Session.query(models.User.user_id).filter_by(username=username)` and I would just need to remove the session when the request ends:

```py
@app.teardown_request
def close_db_session(exception):
    Session.commit()
    Session.remove()
```

---

I am a bit lost with this session management topic and I would need help to understand how to manage sessions. Is there a real difference between the two approaches above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach of managing the session via `flask.g` is completely acceptable to my point of view. Whatever we are trying to do with SQLAlchemy, one must remember the basic principles:

1. Always clean up after yourself. At web application runtime, if you spawn a lot of sessions without `.close()`ing them, this will eventually lead to connection overflow at your DB instance. You are handling this by calling `finally: session.close()`
2. Maintain session independence. It's not good if various application contexts ( requests, threads, etc..) share the same session instance, because it's not deterministic. You are doing this by ensuring only one session runs per one request.

The `scoped_session` can be considered as just an alternative of `flask.g` - it ensures that within one thread, each call to the `Session()` constructor returns the same object - https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html#unitofwork-contextual

It's a SQLA batteries included version of your session management code.

So far, if you are using Flask, which is a synchronous framework, I don't think you will have any issues with this setup.

Comment: Ok so you don't recommend me to switch and use scoped sessions?

Comment: I was saying that your way of managing sessions is totally fine.
I consider it more as a matter of taste, you can obviously replace your session management code with `Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(...))`, but you'll have to ensure it's removed at the end of the request, so no big advantages.